# @depends annotation in Codeception not working with test from different class

Tags: php, testing, automated-tests, codeception

I have this test in `tests\api\LoginCest.php`:

```
class LoginCest {

   public function login( ApiTester $I ) {
      $I->assertTrue( true );
   }

}
```

and this test in a different class, `tests\api\UpdateUserCest.php`:

```
class UpdateUserCest {

   /**
    * @depends LoginCest:login
    */

   public function updateUser( ApiTester $I ) {
      $I->assertTrue( true );
   }

}
```

Note that in the `@depends` annotation I'm using the first test signature `LoginCest:login`, as suggested in the Codeception docs:

> @depends applies to the Cest and Codeception\Test\Unit formats.
> Dependencies can be set across different classes. To specify a
> dependent test from another file you should provide a test signature.
> Normally, the test signature matches the className:methodName format.
> But to get the exact test signature just run the test with the --steps
> option to see it:

I have verified that the signature for the first test is `LoginCest:login`. However when I run the second test it fails because it says the first test was skipped. More precisely, the console says:

> UpdateUserCest: Update user Signature: UpdateUserCest:updateUser Test:
> tests/api/UpdateUserCest.php:updateUser
> Scenario --
> SKIPPED: This test depends on LoginCest:testLogin to pass

and then:

> There was 1 skipped test:
> --------- 1) UpdateUserCest: Update user  Test  tests/api/UpdateUserCest.php:updateUser This test depends on
> LoginCest:login to pass
>
> OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests! Tests: 1, Assertions: 0,
> Skipped: 1.

What am I missing?

Comment: Codeception doesn't sort tests based on dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Per [AdvancedUsage - Codeception 4 Documentation](https://codeception.com/docs/4.x/AdvancedUsage)

> To specify a dependent test from another file you should provide a test signature.
> Normally, the test signature matches the className:methodName format.
> But to get the exact test signature just run the test with the --steps
> option to see it

Usually test signature is:

```
Signature: LoginCest:login
```

But note, that the signature can also contain a namespace:

```
Signature: MyProject\Tests\LoginCest:login
```

Make sure you use proper test signature. Run the tests with --steps option and copy the test signature from there.

Codeception indeed sort tests based on dependencies, and this is great feature to use.

Answer (score 0):

`@depends` mean, that the test only is being executed, if the one, which you are depending on was passing successfully.

So if you want to call "login" before you call "updateUser" in your example, you should use the annotation `@before`.

The second thing is, that I guess that this behaviour only work, if both methods are in the same test class. So this should be work:

```php
class UpdateUserCest
{
    public function login(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->assertTrue(true);
    }

    /**
     * @before login
     */
    public function updateUser(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

now you can explicitly run your update user test and can be sure, the login method is called before.

`codecept.phar run test/api/UpdateUserCest.php:updateUser`

Comment: It's worth noting that `@depends` accepts `Class:method` patterns to involve tests from other classes, but `@before` does NOT. This means you can make the test dependent across classes, but can't automatically invoke the dependencies. If you need a test from another class to run, you're (currently) better off defining a group in your YAML file.